# Load CSV using Pig

Tags: csv, apache-pig

I'm trying to load a CSV file using `Pig`, but the CSV file already contains 'commas' in some of the columns, so using PigStorage(',') is giving me wrong answers.

I have already tried these:

```
REGISTER /......./piggybank.jar

LOAD '...PATH_TO_INPUT_FILE' USING CSVLoader(',') AS (...fieldnames)
```

and

```
LOAD '...PATH_TO_INPUT_FILE' USING CSVExcelStorage(',') AS (...fieldnames)
```

Both all of them are not giving the desired result. The record which does not contain comma in their values they are working fine but rest of them are not.

Comment: Can you post a couple of input lines from the data set that you are trying to process?

Comment: So you have a CSV file with comma separated values, but some of the values contain commas and are not escaped in any way? If that's the case you are in trouble...

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined the method CSVLoader() or CSVExcelStorage() ?

```
DEFINE CSVLoader org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVLoader();
```

OR

```
DEFINE CSVExcelStorage() org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage();
```

Or else you can refer the method directly like this

```
LOAD 'test.txt' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVLoader(',')
LOAD 'test.txt' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage(',')
```

Comment: Haven't tried the DEFINE one, but tried the other two:
LOAD 'test.txt' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVLoader(',')
LOAD 'test.txt' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage(',')

It's not working.